# Eclipse not detecting Nexus 7 tablet for debugging

Tags: android, debugging, device

Debugging mode is turned on.  "windows has determined the driver software for your device is up to date".  Not sure what else to do at this point.

Comment: what usb mode are you using - do you have options like "connect as camera"?

Comment: update your usb driver

Comment: I am getting the options to:

Comment: try adb kill and adb start-server for first. For second -  check in your device manager that all devices determines correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Install the [google usb drivers](http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html) which are required for android development on the Nexus 7.

Make sure you've rebooted afterwards and ensure you can see the contents of your device in windows explorer.